# strip out binary data from text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains some binary data.  When I read the file, using Python 3, in text mode I get an UniCodeDecodeError (codec can't decode byte...) with the following lines of code:

```
fo = open('myfile.txt, 'r')
for line in inFile:
```

How can I remove the binary data from my file.  I have a header that is printed just before each binary data (in this case it is shown as Data Block).  For example, my file looks like such where I want to remove the çºí?¼È×“ñdí:

myfile.txt:

```
ABCDEFGH
123456
Data Block 11
çºí?¼È×“ñdí
XYZ123
```

The result I want is for myfile.txt to look like this:

```
ABCDEFGH
123456
Data Block 11
XYZ123
```

Comment: All text is binary, really. It'd be really weird to have arbitrary random binary blobs mixed in with text. Maybe you're just trying to read the file in the wrong encoding? Maybe those parts are "foreign" words?

Comment: Yes I agree it is wierd but these files actually contain random binary blobs.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is difficult, because "binary" blobs *may* contain valid characters or character sequences.  And if you're using a file that has "text" using multi-byte encoding, forget about it.

If you *know* the "text" in your file only contains single-byte characters, one approach would be to read the file in as bytes, then use something like

```
encode('ascii', error='ignore')
```

This effectively strips non-ascii characters out of the output, but if you were to do this on your file, you'd get:

```
ABCDEFGH
123456
Data Block
?d
XYZ123
```

Note the second to last line -- valid ascii characters were found in the blob and treated as "text".

You may start with a solution like that, and fine-tune it (if possible) to meet your needs.  Maybe the blobs occur by themselves on lines so that if a line has *any* non-ascii characters, throw out the entire line completely.  Maybe you can look at the blobs and try to grok some structure it has.  Maybe you just settle for having random lines of partial characters in there and handle them somehow later.  It's kind of application-specific at that point.

Here's the code I used to produce that output from your sample input:

```
def strip_nonascii(b):
    return b.decode('ascii', errors='ignore')

with open('garbled.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(strip_nonascii(line), end='')
```

Comment: If the data block were to specify the size of the binary data (as I edited my original post to show 11 for 11 bytes of binary data) would that help to strip it out?

Comment: It would.  If there's an easy way to get to the start of the blob (maybe it starts right after the data block, which ends in a newline), then `f.seek(<blob size in bytes>, 1)` would "skip" your read pointer to the first non-blob byte after the blob.

Answer (score -1):

If you also have footer after binary data (like you are having header), try to replace everything between header/footer with nothing with regexp?

Comment: There is no footer per say.  Although the header does tell me how many bytes of binary data is to follow.  I'm  not sure how to use regex since the only way for me to read the file without errors is if I read it in binary mode.